# How to filter a list of items having a child list to remove not allowed items in C# using Linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a two tiers list object and I am trying to select desire data into another list. Please refer to the following model and sample data.

In this example, I want to select only "user_access==true" from the list but unable to get it right. The data in the "Options" section is not filtered.
What I have tried,

```
menudata = menusetup.Where(e => e.user_access == true)
                    .Where(e => e.Options.Any(s => s.user_access == true)).ToList();
```

Please advice.

Thanks

```
private class MenuModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; } // menu type
    public List<MenuModel> Options { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public bool user_access { get; set; } = false;
    public bool vendor_access { get; set; } = false;
}
```

and sample list data

```
private List<MenuModel> menusetup = new List<MenuModel>
{
    new MenuModel {
        Id = "menu",
        Value = "Products",
        user_access = true,
        Options = new List<MenuModel>
        {
            new MenuModel { Value= "Account Group", imgUrl= "\accountgroup", user_access=false },
            new MenuModel { Value= "Angular", imgUrl= "angular", user_access=true },
            new MenuModel { Value= "ASP.NET Core", imgUrl= "core", user_access=false },
            new MenuModel { Value= "ASP.NET MVC", imgUrl= "mvc" , user_access=true}
        }
    },
    new MenuModel {
        Id = "menu",
        Value = "Services",
        Options = new List<MenuModel>
        {
            new MenuModel { Value= "Application Development", Count= "1200+" },
            new MenuModel { Value= "Maintenance & Support", Count= "3700+" },
            new MenuModel { Value= "Quality Assurance" },
            new MenuModel { Value= "Cloud Integration", Count= "900+" }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional info, my expectation for new list is as below

```
{ 
  Id = "menu",
  Value = "Products",
  user_access = true,
  Options
  {
    { Value= "Angular", imgUrl= "angular", user_access=true },
    { Value= "ASP.NET MVC", imgUrl= "mvc" , user_access=true}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a second `.Where`, I would try to cut that and see if it works correctly with only the first `.Where`

Comment: Your current query returns all items from `menusetup` which are *both* 1. meet `user_access==true` and 2. Have *at least one* option among `Options` which is `user_access == true`

Comment: Olivier, that does not work. It doesn't filter "Options" user_access either.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I have added the expected output in my question body. As for the"ID", please ignore that. It is used to identify if it is a menu group. Thnks

Comment: @WilsonTeo Would a  name like `Gender` or `Kind` or `Category` or similar be more appropriate instead of `Id` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Requirement**: query all MenuModels from the menuSetup sequence that have a true UserAccess, each MenuModel with its Options that have a true UserAccess.

```
var result = menuSetups.Where(menuSetup => menuSetup.UserAccess)
    .Select(menuSetup => new
    {
        Id = menuSetup.Id,
        Value = menuSetup.Value,
        UserAccess = true,         // do you really need this? you already know that it's true

        Options = menuSetup.Options
            .Where(option => option.UserAccess)
            .Select(option = > new
            {
                Id = option.Id,
                Value = option.Value,
                UserAccess = true,
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

In words: from the sequence of menuSetups, keep only those menuSetups with a true value for UserAccess. From every remaining menuSetup get properties ...

Keep only those Options of each remaining menuSetup that have a true value for UserAccess. and select properties ...,

**Several advices**

It is more efficient if you only select properties that you actually plan to use. Don't select foreign keys, nor other values of which you already know the value.

Don't use "UserAccess == true". It gives others the impression that you don't understand Booleans. This coding style leads to:

```
if (a == true)
    b = true;
else
    b = false;
```

Instead of:

```
b = a;
```